# What's the difference between Time-lapse, Hyperlapse and Flow Motion?

Tags: timelapse

I want to know specifically what differs between a Time-lapse video and a Hyperlapse video and a Flow Motion video. In question is the accurate definition of the category of this [video](https://vimeo.com/117770305)

Thank you very much for your help in advance.